# Preventing automatic addition of IME when using remote desktop?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, keyboard-layout, ime

I have only one English IME: "English (United Kingdom)" with the "US QWERTY" layout. I know that this is probably a very rare configuration. The problem is that Windows randomly adds "English (United States)" or "English (United Kingdom)" with the "UK QWERTY" layout, when I use remote desktop. My guess is that RDP may be adding the IME of the remote computer, but this automatically added IME does not go away even after closing RDP, so this should be a bug.

That automatically added IME/Keyboard shows up in the Win+Space list or in the notification era, but not in the "Language" page of the Settings. So, to remove that automatically added one, I have to do some weird thing: I have to first add the same thing in the "Language" page of the Settings, and then remove it from there. This has been happening for years. Is there any solution to prevent the addition or make the automatically-added IME go away after closing RDP?

[image]